# Porque Netbeans sugere melhorar o for?

Tags: java, netbeans, convenções

Quando estava fazendo este `for` o Netbeans mostrou aquela lâmpada de dicas para melhorar o código na linha do `for`. A sugestão foi inverter a condição. Segue o código:

**Antes** da melhoria:

```
for(int j = 0; j < selectionPaths.length; j++) {
   if( isDescendant(selectionPaths[j], path) )
      return true;
}
```

**Depois** da melhoria sugerida pelo Netbeans:

```
for(int j = 0; selectionPaths.length >= j; j++) {
   if( isDescendant(selectionPaths[j], path) )
      return true;
}
```

**Update:** depois da "melhoria" o programa lança a exceção `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Mas então porque o Netbeans deu essa sugestão se depois de aceita-la o programa dá erro? Há uma razão específica ou apenas questão de convenção de código? Ou é uma falha do Netbeans?

Obs.: A versão do Netbeans é 8.0.1. A sugestão aparece quando o cursor está posicionado na condição, mais precisamente na variável `selectionPaths`.

Comment: Eu uso o Eclipse, faz séculos que não uso o NetBeans, tb estou curioso para saber o que aconteceu no seu caso.

Comment: Na verdade, neste caso, a sugestão correta seria `selectionPaths.length > j` e não `selectionPaths.length >= j`.

Comment: Porque ele é um software que não olha o contexto, para isto existe o programador.

Comment: Pois é. Talvez por isso ele esteja ali como 'dica' e não refatoração. Refatoração é, vagamente, melhorar o código sem alterar seu comportamento.

Comment: @Earendul eu tentei reproduzir o mesmo cenário e a "correção/sugestão" surtiu em outro resultado (diferente do teu). Ele colocou um for aprimorado. Qual a tua versão mesmo?

Comment: @Cold Sim, pra mim tb ele deu essa sugestão. Experimente colocar o cursor na condição e veja se ele dá outra sugestão. Minha versão é 8.0.1

Comment: Concordo com os comentários anteriores, e gostaria de acrescentar que este `for` pode ser que tenha como ser melhorado: se nem a função `isDescendant` nem outra `thread` alterar `selectionPaths`, pode-se salvar o valor de `length` antes do `for`, evitando a chamada sucessiva a esta propriedade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Netbeans analisa apenas o código, não o contexto no qual esse está inserido, ou seja, se seu código pode ser refatorado, ele vai te dar uma sugestão, porém ele não vai verificar todo o seu código para sugerir uma refatoração "decente". Portanto é escolha do programador aceitar ou não a escolha do IDE.

Caso você aceite qualquer sugestão do IDE, tenha em mente que será necessário um reajuste de código para que ela seja plausível de funcionamento. Em outras palavras, em 70% dos casos o NetBeans dá algumas sugestões boas, mas nos outros 30% ele fala algumas coisas sem sentido que vai depender da experiência do programador para funcionar.

Como foi dito já nos comentários, isso é assunto para uma grade discussão sobre gostos, existem pessoas que preferem códigos de um modo e pessoas que preferem de outro modo, é a mesma coisa de ter:

```
If() {

}
```

e

```
if()
{

}
```

Vai de gosto.

Comment: Se ele realmente está sugerindo Refatoração então ele está sugerindo errado, pois neste caso, há alteração de comportamento com a mudança sugerida, o que vai contra o conceito de Refatoração.

Comment: É uma questão de inteligencia de software creio eu. Como ele não analisa todo seu código ele é sujeito a alguns erros locais de blocos específicos.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso em específico é por questão de boas práticas e convenções.

Ex:

Da maneira que fez `j < selectionPaths.length;` se por um descuido colocar o sinal `=` em vez de `<` você estaria atribuindo o `selectionPaths.length` ao `j`.

Já o exemplo sugerido `selectionPaths.length >= j` também atribui no javascript mas em outras linguagens ou se `selectionPaths.length` fosse um método (`selectionPaths.length()`) e se equivocasse colocando o `=` em vez de `>=` iria ocorrer um erro de sintaxe sendo portanto mais fácil de identificar que um erro de lógica desse nível.

Comment: Na verdade isso não é possível de acontecer no Java. Se você fizer `if(1)` ele simplesmente não compila, pois o `if` espera um boleano, e não aceita nada diferente disso em hipótese alguma. O mesmo vale para o `for` e o `while`. Logo, se você fizer `j=selectionPaths.length` você terá um inteiro onde deveria ter um boleano e consequentemente a própria IDE te avisará do erro antes mesmo de tentar compilar. Portanto, a sua resposta não justifica a inversão da ordem da comparação.

Comment: Além disso "evitar o risco do programador se confundir e fazer uma atribuição indevida" é uma melhoria marginal a um custo alto que é a inversão da lógica de comparação, e está longe de ser uma boa prática ou convenção (eu pelo menos nunca vi essa recomendação em lugar nenhum). É diferente por exemplo de fazer `"A".equals(string)` em vez de  `string.equals("A")` que neste caso tem um objetivo claro e consistente (eliminar o risco de chamar o método `equals` a partir de uma variável potencialmente `null`).