# Netbeans: mensagem de aviso

Tags: php, netbeans

Tenho uma mensagem de aviso que me diz que o **método** é 23 linhas e entre parenteses diz **(20 permitido)** não entendi o porque desta mensagem, segue abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que significa isso? tem como desativar esse aviso?

Comment: Relacionado: [Porque Netbeans sugere melhorar o for?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38774/91). Não vá muito nas ideias do netbeans rs

Comment: Sempre que alguém tiver algum aviso desses é ir ver aos *Hints* que deve lá estar a causa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É uma dica de que seu método poderia ser melhor, talvez dividindo-o em sub-métodos. Mas isso não precisa ser seguido à risca e nem sempre quer dizer que seu código pode ser melhorado.

Você pode desativar ou configurar essas dicas em:

- Ferramentas -> Opções -> Editor -> Dicas (EN: Tools->Options->Editor->Hints)
- Escolha a linguagem, no seu caso PHP
- Procure a opção 'Muitas linhas' (EN: "Too Many Lines") e configure ou desmarque a opção para desativar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: EN: Tools->Options->Editor na aba Hints selecione PHP e procure "Too Many Lines"

Comment: @JorgeB. Boa, adicionei na resposta, ;)

Answer (score 2):

Parece que o netbeans tem alguma ferramenta que verifica o código, nesse caso ele sugere que o método tenha 20 linhas no maximo, outras opções podem são checkspelling, tamanho minimo em nomes de variáveis etc.

Answer (score 2):

Nada demais com que se tenha de preocupar a sério. Apenas uma mensagem que o IDE gera a partir de uma configuração que pode parametrizar em número de linhas.

A ideia que está para este tipo de controle tem a ver com algumas regras de boas práticas de desenvolvimento que o IDE implementa ou pode ajudar. Uma delas é que quanto menor o número de linhas em uma função mais eficaz esta pode ser e melhor legibilidade o seu código tem.

Para modificar este comportamento pode em: **Tools->Options->Editor**, no tabulador **Hints** selecione a opção "Too Many Lines" > "Function (Method) Declaration. POr defeito é 20.